# How to sort data as I want in a VirtualExplorerTreeview (VirtualShellTools)

Tags: delphi, components

This is probably a very "dumb" question for whoever knows VirtualShellTools but I only started using it and couldn't find my answer in the demos' code. Please note that I'm also unfamiliar with virtualtreeview.

I use a VirtualExplorerTreeview to display a directory structure, linked with a VirtualExplorerListview to display a certain type of files in the selected directory as well as specific informations about them

I've been able to point them at the right place, link them as I wanted, filter everything in the listview, and looking at the demos I have a pretty good idea about how to add my own columns and draw it to display my custom data.

My issue lies with the Treeview: I would like to sort the directories displayed in the order I want; specifically, I want "My Docs" and other folder to appears first, then drives, then removable media. Looking in the TNamespace property I found how to distinguish them (Directory and Removable properties), but I don't know how to implement my own sort/what event I need. I tried CompareNode but that doesn't even seem to be called.

Comment: That second part is TOTALLY unrelated to sorting. You would best move that to a separate question about adding virtual namespaces.

Comment: yeah i think you're right, i removed it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do everything yourself, then set `toUserSort` in the `TVirtualExplorerTree.TreeOptions.VETMiscOptions` property. That causes the control to just use the `DoCompare` method inherited from the virtual tree view, and that should call the `OnCompareNodes` event handler.

A better way is to provide a custom `TShellSortHelper`. Make a descendant of that class and override whichever methods you need. Create an instance of that class and assign it to the tree's `SortHelper` property. (The tree takes ownership of the helper; free the old one, but not the new one.) If the items are being sorted on a column that that class doesn't know how to compare, then handle the tree's `OnCustomColumnCompare` event.

To help you figure out exactly which methods you need to override or events you need to handle, set a breakpoint in `TCustomVirtualExplorerTree.DoCompare` and step through to see what gets called in various situations.